# How can I fix the attribute error in VS code when the same code runs perfectly on colab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pip, jupyter, attributeerror, modulenotfounderror

I was running the [PySINDy](https://pysindy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package and I kept on getting the module not found-error when I ran this:

```
pip install pysindy
import pysindy as ps
```

I fixed this by downgrading the Python in my VS code to 3.8.9. But I do get the following note:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

I am now getting the attribute error when I run the following:

```
differentiation_method = ps.FiniteDifference(order=2)
```

Here's the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pysindy' has no attribute 'differentiation'
```

Can someone please help me with this? (I successfully ran the entire code earlier on google colab and the online Jupyter, but I am unable to do it locally. I use MAC os and Jupyter via VS Code.)